# Why does it take so long to debug/deploy my app to my device?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I am currently trying to debug / deploy my app (Xamarin.Forms) to my device.
And everytime I do it takes at least 5 minutes to get it started on the iPhone.
It's not a heavy app at all, it has a textbox on it and thats it.

I am currently deploying from Visual Studio on Windows and the iPhone is connected to the mac.

Device: iPhone 7
Slow as in 5+ minutes to deploy

I tried changing a few of the build options to this but it's just as slow.
New to Xamarin.Forms so I am not sure what's going on here.
[image]

Comment: Do you have x86_64 as option under supported architecture ?. as Ios can run on 32 and 64 bit modes. Could you try by selecting this option?

Comment: @Prany THis is what I have https://i.imgur.com/9qR66eR.png

Comment: ahh right, it is real iPhone not simulator. Can you try by closing Visual Studio then delete bin , obj from your project(take backup) and finally start visual studio Build and Run

Comment: @Prany still really really slow

Comment: I've got one improvement tips/tricks for you. - https://github.com/brminnick/ImproveXamarinBuildTimes. Hopefully it'll help